# Is weak Hilbert Nullstellensatz's theorem "if and only if"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question is quite simple, I would like to know if the weak Hilbert Nullstellensatz's theorem can be "if and only if":

**Nullstellensatz theorem**

If $I\subset k[X_1,\ldots,X_n]$ is a proper ideal, then $V(I)\neq \emptyset$

Thanks

Comment: The converse statement is: If $I = (1)$ then $V(I) = \emptyset$. Now this is true!

Comment: @Benja so, the "if and only if" is true.

Comment: By the way, the German word "Satz" means "theorem". Thus "Nullstellensatz theorem" is redundant. And if you want to put a 's somewhere, it's Hilbert's ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $A = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.

The weak Nullstellensatz says:

> If $I \neq (1)$ in $A$, then $V(I) \neq \emptyset$.

The converse is: if $V(I) \neq \emptyset$, then $I \neq (1)$.

We can prove this by contrapositive: suppose $I = (1)$, then $V(I) = \{P$ prime such that $I \subseteq P\}$, but there is no prime ideal that contains $I = (1)$, since prime ideals must be proper. Conclude that $V(I) = \emptyset$.